# typesetting the document which fits into marked fixed lines

Tags: fontsize, typography, line-spacing

I have a to typeset the article such that, the output should be printed on the fixed marks that are 1.36 cms apart.

In other words, printing sheet has marked lines which are 1.36 cms apart. I have to type with font 11 or 12 whcih fits into these marked lines.[image] Also, how can decide the maximum font size that i can fit between any two fixed lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than use `\large` and friends, you want to set the font size and baseline skip "by hand"

```
 \fontsize{1cm}{1.36cm}\selectfont
```

The first size is the font size, you will just need to choose that by eye, depending on which font you are using. The second is baselineskip.

You also then want to set `\parskip` to a multiple of `\baselineskip` so it does not push you off grid at a new paragraph. That is, in your preamble go something like

```
 \raggedbottom
 \newlength\myline
 \setlength{\myline}{1.36cm}
 \setlength{\parskip}{0\myline}% this puts no vertical space between paragraphs
 %\setlength{\parskip}{1\myline}% uncomment this if you want exactly one blank line
```

If you just have text and paragraph breaks, that should be enough. If you also have (say) itemized lists you will need to similarly set spaces such as `\itemsep` to be a multiple of `\myline` so that the itemized points still end up between your lines.

Comment: If i use the command, its fine for the first line. What i should do for second line? Can you elaborate. I am not an  expert in TeX.

Comment: answer expanded with code fragment as requested

Answer (score 6):

To see what is happening use the following MWE

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\hrule
\vrule height1.36cm \hbox{\HUGE Test a line of texg}
\hrule
\vrule height1.36cm \hbox to 1.36cm{\Huge Test a line of texg}
\hrule
\vrule height1.36cm \hbox to 1.36cm{\huge Test a line of texg}
\hrule
\medskip

\baselineskip1.36cm
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

If a `0.4pt` accuracy is important to you, adjust `vrule` by changing the lines to:

```
\vrule height\dimexpr1.36cm-0.4pt \hbox to 1.36cm{\HUGE Test a line of texg}
```

[image]

You can select a reasonable size after the test, or simply use:

```
\fontsize{1.13cm}{1.36cm}\selectfont
```

(try and keep a ratio of 1.2-1.3).

Comment: You probably want to reduce the height of the vrule by 0.4pt to take account of the width of the hrule (also specifying the width of the hbox just makes the boxes over full, so I think just `\hbox{...` would work as well.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- point taken on `hbox` typed in error. I did not reduce the 0.4pt in order not to over complicate the example. What I wanted to say visualize a bit, give it a try, select one of the standard sizes or just adjust the size with fontsize, but I think you said it better:)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides, How do you remove the vertical line?

Comment: @Anil remove the `\vrule height1.36cm`.